# AttributeError when using Enums (Python 3.5) in Django Model

Tags: python, django, enums

I'm trying to use Enums on Python 3.5 in my Django model. Why am I getting this when trying to migrate?

```
field=models.CharField(choices=[('RE', 'Red'), ('GR', 'Green'), ('BL', 'Blue'), ('OR', 'Orange'), ('YE', 'Yellow'), ('PU', 'Purple')], default=users.models.COLOR('BL'), max_length=2),
AttributeError: module 'users.models' has no attribute 'COLOR'
```

-

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

  class COLOR(enum.Enum):
    RED = 'RE'
    GREEN = 'GR'
    BLUE = 'BL'
    ORANGE = 'OR'
    YELLOW = 'YE'
    PURPLE = 'PU'

  //...
  color = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=((x.value, x.name.title()) for x in COLOR), default=COLOR.BLUE)
```

Comment: 3.4 and 3.5 are different versions.

Comment: @user2357112 that's a typo, I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices I think this will help you.

Comment: @Wencakisa I'm trying to use enums instead just declaring the constants. The error is thrown on the default line, not on the choices line.

Comment: Why are you trying to specify an enum value as the default there, anyway? I don't think Django would even recognize what `COLOR.BLUE` is, even if you specified it correctly.

Comment: Hey, the code in the error message isn't the same as the code you posted! The code you posted has an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a `CharField` on the model, you can not pass an enum instance (`default=COLOR.BLUE`) as the default value.  You should pass a string instead.

The better way to do this is to define a custom field which knows how to clean enum instances.  If you rather to keep things simple and stick to the `CharField` on the model, then just pass the enum value explicitly (`default='BL'`).